Disable validation of reference on change
I have a reference input with a select input. When I change the selected value a request is triggered.
This cause issue when the value I want is not the ID. Is there a way to disable that?
It seems to be for form validation.
Thanks !

Follow this code, and adjust this function based on your criteria. I hope it will helps you.
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const YourComponent = () => {
    const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState('');
    const [triggerRequest, setTriggerRequest] = useState(false);

    const handleSelectChange = (e) => {
        const value = e.target.value;
        setSelectedValue(value);

        setTriggerRequest(false);

        // Set triggerRequest true if the value meets your criteria
        if (isValidID(value)) {
          setTriggerRequest(true);
        }
    };

    const isValidID = (value) => {
        // Replace this with your own validation logic
        return value.startsWith('ID_');
    };

    const handleSubmit = () => {
        if (triggerRequest) {
            console.log(`Request triggered with ID: ${selectedValue}`);
        } else {
            console.log('Invalid ID, request not triggered.');
        }
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <select value={selectedValue} onChange={handleSelectChange}>
              <option value="">Select an option</option>
              <option value="ID_1">Option 1</option>
              <option value="ID_2">Option 2</option>
              <option value="ID_3">Option 3</option>
            </select>
            <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default YourComponent;


Hi @kaamrul, I wish it would as I am on this problem since 3 days. Unfortunately, this question is specific to react admin. You can read more here about the component that cause this sadly unnecessary request https://marmelab.com/react-admin/ReferenceInput.html

For instance, if you pass here : https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/v4.16.19/packages/ra-core/src/controller/input/useReferenceInputController.ts#L119  the enabled: false , then you disable the validation.
I can solve it with patch-package and adding a new props, or just importing the chain of files and use my version.
Sad that react-admin did not propose a workaround for that case

it is not possible to disable validation,
how ever, it is possible to create a patch, adding a props and allow to set enabled: false here : https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/v4.16.19/packages/ra-core/src/controller/input/useReferenceInputController.ts#L119
